# Shouldn’t the possessive article show accusative or dative case after ‘über’?

Tags: grammatical-case, article, possessive

In a German textbook I see a sentence:

> Er freut sich über dein Besuch.

Dein is a possesive article following variation like indefinite article. *Dein* is nominitive form. Why is it not in accusative (*deinen*) or dative (*deinem*) form?

Comment: It should be `deinen` (accusative), you are perfectly right.

Comment: @Lebenita That's a relief in that my understanding was correct. I'm a beginner in German.  BTW, I added another question. Could you answer it too? And are you a native German? :)

Comment: The other sentence is correct however: *Wir treffen und in der Bank*; while *Bank* is female, the article becomes *der* in the dative case.

Comment: @guidot What am I doing, I knew der was correct but misread the sentence was wrong (when it is der) :).

Comment: I don’t quite get your second uncertainty; you are confused why it is *der* but you are suggesting *der* or *die?* Also, since the two are not really related (there is no *über* in the second one) you should remove it and ask it in a separate question. Actually, thinking about it, I’ll remove it for you.

Comment: @Chan-Kim Have you tried looking for a list of published errata for your textbook? Or contacted the publisher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That first sentence from the textbook is definitely wrong. I saw many German textbooks abroad, which seem to never have been proofread by a native speaker, let alone a linguist. Sometimes such false sentences are part of exercises, but then this should be clearly marked.

The pronoun has to be in accusative case:

> Er freut sich über **deinen** Besuch.

(ask: Er freut sich über *wen*/*was*?)

Comment: The second sentence should not have been part of the question since it is an entirely separate issue. I have removed it from the question, you should remove it from your answer, too :)

Comment: done, thanks. it might have been valid if the question were "can I trust my textbook".